# В нахождении каких типов ошибок верификация ПО эффективнее, чем тестирование ПО?

Tags: тестирование

- Редко встречающиеся критические ошибки
- Часто встречающиеся мелкие ошибки
- Редко встречающиеся мелкие ошибки
- Часто встречающиеся критические ошибки

Я думаю, что это **часто встречающиеся мелкие ошибки и редко встречающиеся мелкие ошибки**, но не уверен.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под верификацией и тестированием уточните и добавьте в вопрос. И что верифицируете?

Comment: @AzizUmarov верификация и тестирование ПО

Comment: А как верифицируете?

Comment: Зависит от субъективных мнений задавшего вопрос (например, преподавателя)